# Reusing code for Unit Tests where method changes

Tags: python, unit-testing

I know the title is very poor but I cannot think of a more eloquent way of stating the issue. I have a lot of unit tests:

```
 def test_send_new_registration_email(self):
    emails = NewEmail(email_client=MagicMock())
    emails.send_email = MagicMock()
    emails.send_marketing_email(recipients(), new_registration_payload())
    emails.send_email.assert_called_with(new_registration_output())
```

and

```
  def test_send_new_comment_email(self):
    emails = NewEmail(email_client=MagicMock())
    emails.send_email = MagicMock()
    emails.send_marketing_email(recipients(), new_registration_payload())
    emails.send_email.assert_called_with(new_comment_output())
```

There are twenty of these unit tests. All follow very similar patterns. Basically I compare the input to desired output. There must be a way to have a list of inputs and a list of outputs and compare.

I could do a for loop e.g.

```
def test_send_new_registration_email(self):
    for index, input in enum(inputs):
        emails = NewEmail(email_client=MagicMock())
        emails.send_email = MagicMock()
        emails.send_marketing_email(input)
        emails.send_email.assert_called_with(output[index])
```

However is there a cleaner way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for parameterized tests. However, the actual implementation depends on what library you are using for unit testing. The vanilla `unittest` does not provide any support for parameterizing, so you will need to install third-party packages. An example with [`parameterized`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parameterized/0.6.1) (`pip install parameterized`):

```
from parameterized import parameterized

@parameterized.expand([
    ((recipients(), new_registration_payload(), ), new_registration_output(), ),
    ((recipients(), new_registration_payload(), ), new_comment_output(), ),
])
def test_send_new_comment_email(self, input, output):
    emails = NewEmail(email_client=MagicMock())
    emails.send_email = MagicMock()
    emails.send_marketing_email(*input)
    emails.send_email.assert_called_with(output)
```

The test will now be executed twice with both the test inputs provided.

If you intend to write and run your tests with [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) instead (this is what I'm using myself), it already offers parameterizing of tests out of the box:

```
import pytest

data = [
    ((recipients(), new_registration_payload(), ), new_registration_output(), ),
    ((recipients(), new_registration_payload(), ), new_comment_output(), ),
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("input, output", data)
def test_send_new_comment_email(input, output):
    emails = NewEmail(email_client=MagicMock())
    emails.send_email = MagicMock()
    emails.send_marketing_email(*input)
    emails.send_email.assert_called_with(output)
```

The test will be run twice:

```
$ pytest test_foo.py --collect-only

======== test session starts ========
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.2.5, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /private/tmp, inifile:
plugins: mock-1.6.3, cov-2.5.1
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                          

<Module 'test_foo.py'>
    <Function 'test_send_new_comment_email[input0-registration_output]'>
    <Function 'test_send_new_comment_email[input1-comment_output]'>

======== no tests ran in 0.01 seconds ========
```